# Using Angular2 InMemoryDbService

Tags: angular

I am using InMemoryDbService to store some static data for my application.

Example function fetching data from InMemorDbService:

```
import { InMemoryDbService } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';

public getDepartmentStaticData() {
    return Promise.all([
      this.http.get("api/departments/?section=section1").toPromise(),                        
    ]);      
}
```

I am now trying to fetch data from a backend server but calls are not reaching the server:

Example function:

```
public getProducts() {
    console.log('CategoryService.getProducts called')
    return this.http.get('/api/products/all')
    .map((response:Response) => {
      console.log("getProducts done **********************")
    })
}
```

I am wondering if angular is capable of distinguishing calls to InMemorDbService from calls to the backend server or is it forwarding all calls to the InMemorDbService only. I cannot figure why calls to my node server is not hitting the server.

In short is it possible to use both InMemoryDBService and a backend server simultaneously?

Comment: https://github.com/angular/in-memory-web-api#request-evaluation-order

Comment: Problem solved, thank you, JB.